# Determining What Volumes EC2 Partitions Point To

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

I have a medium high CPU EC2 instance setup. How do I know what volumes the devices listed in /proc/partitions map to? If I `cat /proc/partitions` I get the following:

```
# cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

202       65    6291456 xvde1
202      144  356485632 xvdj
202       67     917504 xvde3
202      176   10485760 xvdl
```

I am pretty sure the first one is the root volume. I also created a second volume for log files, etc. I know that volume is 10GB so I am pretty sure that is `xvdl`.

I have no idea what `xvdj` is. It looks like its 356 GB!?  Is that available for me to use? How do I know what it is and how do I use it?

Answer (score 0):

If you type `mount` you'll see a list of all the filesystems and their devices. If no file system is present on a particular device, you can try using it for other purposes. I've found in the past that I was able to put a file system on one of these unused partitions and use it within the instance.

Comment: It definitely wasn't mounted to anything. I am just curious why its there. I don't want to use it for anything important if I don't even know what it is.

Comment: I don't know why it's there and not used. I can tell you however that I've used it in the same way as the other local partitions with the same reliability etc.